# Run compiled python script from PHP

Tags: php, bash

I need to run a python script, compiled with pyinstaller via a PHP generated webpage. 
I tried shell_exec(), exec() and system() without success.
I regularly run the script from terminal in background using:

```
temperature_sensor_code > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I've added www-data user to sudoers. I know it's not a good way but I need it in order to send killall temperature_sensor_code command (this is works).

This is my situation:

```
<?php

  $run = escapeshellcmd('temperature_sensor_code > /dev/null 2>&1');
  shell_exec($run);

  header("Refresh: 0; URL=index.php");
 ?>
```

I've made a symlink in /usr/bin, also tried with the full path of the script with no luck.

UPDATE: to make it simpler, i've created a simple sh script run.sh and put in /var/www and make it RUN with

```
shell_exec("/var/www/run.sh");
```

this is working for me. So I put my script temperature_sensor_code in /var/www but this is not working. If I add `var_dump(exec("/var/www/temperature_sensor_code/temperature_sensor_code"));`
gives me: **string(0) ""**

I think there are problems with the compiled python script because the PHP side seems to be OK.

Comment: Errors? What is expected result?

Comment: No errors to report from PHP. The python script itself works fine; basically it reads a sensor and store data in MySQL.

Comment: Tried normal exec function?

Comment: @uglypointer already tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[escapeshellcmd()](http://php.net/escapeshellcmd) does this:

> Escape shell metacharacters

```
$run = escapeshellcmd('temperature_sensor_code > /dev/null 2>&1');
var_dump($run);
```

> ```
> string(43) "temperature_sensor_code \> /dev/null 2\>\&1"
> ```

But you have shell metacharacters that you do want to behave as shell metacharacters:

```
temperature_sensor_code > /dev/null 2>&1
                        ^           ^^^^
```

You're also doing no troubleshooting at all:

- You discard all command output (that's what sending it to `/dev/null` does)
- You don't get the return code

I suggest to:

- Switch to [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and make sure you use all its arguments and not just the mandatory ones
- Get rid of `> /dev/null` until you diagnose the issue

Comment: Your suggestions allowed me to find the real problem. Not the PHP configuration but insufficient www-data permission